# KEY + Constraint mysql 5 seems duplicated

Tags: mysql

I used phpMyAdmin to quickly create a database and then manually added constraints via sql. When I looked at the sql dump file it had the following (from mysqldump). To me it seems unnecessary to have both a key and constraint.

IS the KEY and CONSTRAINT duplicated?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `menu_item_option_ingredients`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `menu_item_option_ingredients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_item_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quanity` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `menu_item_option_ingredients_ibfk_1` (`menu_item_option_id`),
  KEY `menu_item_option_ingredients_ibfk_2` (`ingredient_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `menu_item_option_ingredients_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ingredient_id`) REFERENCES `ingredients` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `menu_item_option_ingredients_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_item_option_id`) REFERENCES `menu_item_options` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a constraint without having a key on that constraint, so you can safely remove the keys if you don't want / need them.

Keys and constraints serve different purposes.

EDIT: Actually, let me correct myself. When you add a constraint in InnoDb, it is always automatically indexed which shows up as a key (they are synonymous). What you are seeing in the show create table is just the indexes that were created.

Comment: What would the disadvantage to just having a constraint?

Comment: IMO the disadvantage of creating a foreign key without an index is that the implicitly created index has a generated name.

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes the generated names may be easier to use because they have a strict format (useful for generalizing code), but if you want a simpler name, then you can specify it yourself (the 'index_name' portion):ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
        FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
        reference_definition

Answer (score 0):

They are not redundant. If you add a foreign key without a key then one will be implicitly created for you, but personally I prefer to explicitly create the key so I can choose its name.